# Quais vantagens o Angular 4 tem sobre o AngularJs 1.6?

Tags: angular

Trabalho com angularJS 1.6 e estou estudando angular4, sei que como toda linguagem e tecnologia passa constantemente por um processo de evolução, mas essa mudanças que o angular teve é recomendado para todos os projetos em angular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O Angular 2/4 é completamente diferente do Angularjs, o Agular 4  é orientado a componentes e é completamente modularizado facilitando alteracões isoladas apenas onde se deseja , caso queira alterar o login voce poderá editar apenas o login , o Angular 4 foi feito com tudo que há de mais novo no mercado ele ultiliza o ECS05, ECS06, typeScript, um gerenciador de pacotes o Angular-cli (como o maven do java) , a forma que o Angular 4 controla suas diretivas não poluindo tanto o DOM faz com que ele tenha uma performace melhor que sua primeira versão.

Porem o Angular-2 precisa do Node.js para funcionar  ele precisa que seja colocado toda sua biblioteca e não mas um link no head como era antes a curva de aprendizado do angularjs é bem menor e nele contem alguns pipes a mais que foram retirados do angular 2  pela equipe de desenvolvimento por questao de performace .

O controle de rotas do Angular-2 é mais simples e robusto contando com as rotas, rotas filhas e guardas de rotas.

Respondendo sua pergunta- é bastante recomendado que seja atualizado para a nova versao se pensar do ponto de vista unico performace sim , deve ser atualizado porem vai muito do se vai realmente ultilizar todas as coisas novas que foram liberadas em sua versão nova pois atualizar por atulizar nao valeria a pena o custo de implementacao e refatoracao de codigo